# Photoshop Batch extract images from PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, batch-processing, photoshop-scripting

When I open a PDF in photoshop I can choose to open one of the images. I've got a massive 2gb pdf with ~700 images in it and I'm trying to export them all to image files. Is there a way for photoshop to extract all the images from a pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the PDF with Photoshop... just tick the **images** option in the upper left corner. All the images will be displayed. You can then shift-click the images you want to open and open them all with one click.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for some kind of answer to do this as I had over 250 images I needed to extract.  I didn't want to do this one by one.  I settled on creating an action then running the File > Automate > Batch command.

I'm not certain on how many images PS will allow you to select and open (as image size and such may be a factor), but I was able to open 100 of the images and run it.  The images were smaller so it took less than a minute to have the images extracted.

I wasn't able to figure out why the file naming I chose in the settings didn't work, but at least the images were exported successfully.

Here are the steps I took to save the images to PNG files ('Save for Web & Devices').

1. Open your PDF file, click on Images radio button and select any image of the images (you will be recording an action so you must go through the steps to save this file into the format you will want your images to be saved to).
2. Go to the 'Actions' panel. If you don't have it open, you must open it through the top menu via View > Actions.
3. In the Actions panel, there are icons on the bottom.  Hover over these and to find the 'Create new action' icon and click on it.  It should open a dialog to name your action.
4. After you've named your action, select it by clicking it on the list of actions and make sure it is highlighted.
5. Go back down to the icons and click on the 'Begin Recording' icon (should be circle icon).
6. Go back to your opened PDF image and make sure it is the active file you are working on.
7. Go to File > Save For Web & Devices > Save as PNG-24 (or jpg or whatever file format you want to save it as) and adjust all settings on this dialog.  Click 'Save' when you are done.  Then go to File > Close to close the image. (Not sure why, but I needed this close step in order for my files to be saved running the batch action.
8. Go back to the Actions panel and click the square icon (Stop Playing/Recording).  Your action is now completed.
9. To run the Batch, (you may want to test on a few files first before opening more than 50 files), make sure no other files are open and open the pdf, click on images radio button at Import dialog, and select the images by clicking and holding down shift key (for multiple in a row) or Ctrl key for specific images.
10. After the images have opened, go to File > Automate > Batch...  In dialog,

    - select your Action from the dropdown menu, Source should be set to 'Opened Files'
    - set Destination to 'Folder', then Choose the folder you want the images to be saved to.
    - Click the 'Override Action 'Save As' Command' check box to set it.
    - Compatibility (click what this should be set to for your project)
    - leave Errors as 'Stop for Errors'
    - Make sure all info in dialog is ok and click 'Ok' to run the Batch.

It should start running the Batch and close out each file as it is saved until all the files are closed.

Check the folder and they should all be in the folder you chose to save them to.
Even if you have to do this in several batches due to file size of images, it is quicker than opening and saving individually.

Another advantage is you can create multiple actions (one for png file, one for jpg file) and run the batch accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not photoshop but I've found another tool which accomplishes this:

http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html